# Why is Ruby on Rails controller variable null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

My goal is to fill an html table in a view (schedule.html.haml):

```
 - if @plans != nil
   %p display this if plans is not null
 - if @plans == nil
   %p= action_name
```

with the data from `@plans` in a controller:

```
def schedule
 @plans = Order.all
end
```

I am sure `Order.all` returns data. Route file is:

`get 'schedule', to: 'order_articles#schedule'`

When I try to do this plans is null. The output is:

```
schedule
```

I tried to check if `plans` is `null` with the code in the view. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is the route and controller action? How are you calling it? What is being rendered? Your code snippet does not provide enough information for anyone to help.

Comment: Nothing in your above code indicates that `@plans` would be `nil`. It should always be a (potentially empty) array. So there must be *something* wrong with how you're calling the controller action/setting the variable, but I don't know what.

Comment: @Elyasin That won't make a difference. `nil` is the singleton instance of `NilClass`; checking `#nil?` is exactly the same thing as checking `== nil`.

Comment: @F. LK, I don't think it will be effective evaluating using `nil`, see my answer below explained how.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a stricter and more sane type coercion scheme than other popular dynamic languages:

```
irb(main):001:0> !!nil
=> false
irb(main):002:0> !![]
=> true
irb(main):003:0> !!""
(irb):3: warning: string literal in condition
=> true
irb(main):004:0> !!0
=> true
```

Everything except `nil` and `false` evaluate to true. `nil` is only equal to `nil`.

`Order.all` will never return nil, if no records are found it returns an empty `ActiveRecord::Collection` object. It's an array like result object telling you there was nothing in the database.

So when dealing with collections you need to use the appropriate methods such as `.any?`, `.none?` etc:

```
- if @plans.any?
   %p display this if there are any plans.
- else
   %p= action_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `present?`, `any?` or `none?` instead of `nil?`.

If you evaluate with `nil?`, it will always return `false` because it always return empty array `[]` if the object does not have any record.

For example:

Your `Order` table doesn't have any record.

```
=> @plans = Order.all
=> @plans.nil?
=> false

=> @plans
=> []
```

And if it has any record?

```
=> @plans = Order.all
=> @plans.nil?
=> false

=> @plans
=> [#<Order:0x007fa2832c0308
 id: 1,
 your_field: 'value'>]
```

> Suggestion #1

View (schedule.html.haml):

```
- if @plans.present?
  %p display this if plans is not null
- else
  %p= action_name
```

> Suggestion #2

View (schedule.html.haml):

```
- if @plans.any?
  %p display this if plans is not null
- else
  %p= action_name
```

> Suggestion #3

View (schedule.html.haml):

```
- if @plans.none?
  %p= action_name
- else
  %p display this if plans is not null
```

Comment: I would say `any?` or `none?` reads much better.  `.present?` is really for checking if the value/key is set and is not a blank value.